# DI container | explicit ServiceProvider error ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, explicit-interface

I want to register my context class that have this implementation:

[UserMangemtentContext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFW7g.png)

I want to using this context to seed data but when I call the `GetService` method on the `serviceProvider`, I get this error:

[image: ERROR]

How can I fix this error?

I tried to register for this service using `GetRequiredService` and other functions but it's not working.